# LZMA library error: No progress is possible

Tags: 16.04, tar, extract

I try to extract a tar file and when I right click on that file and select "extract here" it says to me:

> An error occured while extracting files
>   Lzma library error:  No progress is possible

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> An error occured while extracting files Lzma library error: No progress is possible

That means your archive is corrupt.

> How can i fix this?

Try to get another copy of the archive from wherever you got it from.

Comment: Just a note about this answer: It is not necessariliy caused by a corrupt archive. I seem to be getting this error when my machine runs out of memory (not necessarily due to the actual LZMA library). Still debugging, so I'm not absolutely sure of that, but I am 100% sure that my archive is not corrupt (I can successfily decompress it sometimes). But note that I am not using the GUI to do the extraction, nor am I using the built-in ubuntu packages, so my comment may not be relevent to this specific question.